# Different UI-Elements in dependency of an attribute in WPF/Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two different ToolTip-Layouts:

```
<StackPanel>
   <TextBlock/>
   <StackPanel>
       <Image/>
       <Label/>
   </StackPanel>
 </StackPanel>
```

and

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel>A lot of stuff here </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel>A lot of stuff here </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel>A lot of stuff here </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel>A lot of stuff here </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel>A lot of stuff here </StackPanel>
 </StackPanel>
```

As you can see these two Layouts are completely different.
Now I'd like to either select the first or the second one to be shown as my ToolTip. This should be in dependency of a Binding. Let's say just a boolean. If true, the first layout should be used, if false, the second layout should be used:

```
<TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.ToolTip>
      if (val) 
          firstLayout 
      else 
          secondLayout
   </TextBlock.ToolTip>
</TextBlock>
```

Is it possible to realize it via XAML or do I have to do it in Code-Behind?

Edit: My best approach would be to add both types to my layout and handle it via a visibility attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using **`DataTriggers`**. Default use `FirstLayout` and in case binding value is false, use `SecondLayout`.

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource FirstLayout}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                            Value="{StaticResource SecondLayout}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: excellent! It works like a charme! I'll accept your answere asap ;)